# Jaxb custom binding with eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jaxb, content-assist

I have a jaxb custom bindings file in eclipse (named binding.xjb) and while it opens in the xml editor it won't provide content assist for any of the namespaces I have imported. This makes it very difficult to check the validity of the file.

The top of the file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<jaxb:bindings version="2.0" xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">`
```

Anybody got any idea what I need to do to get content-assist working for this file?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**
Following on from Blaises answer (below), I set:

> ```
> Location:    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd
> KeyType:     Namespace name
> Key          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb
> ```

and now I can see content assist in eclipse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you register an XML schema in the Eclipse XML catalog, then the XML editor will give you content assist when you create a corresponding root element with the appropriate namespace qualification.  Below are the clicks for doing this in Eclipse Juno:

- Open Preferences Window:  `Eclipse` | `Preferences`
- Preferences Window:  `XML` | `XML Catalog` | `Add`

Comment: Ah yes, thanks for this - I'd seen this window before but wasn't sure what it does.